# Reactjs Conditionally hide component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js renders an element from NewNav.tsx. I an trying to conditionally hide the element in App.js. For example I want to hide the element only on a route "/check".

App.js

```
render() {
     return (
           <NewNav />
)
}
```

NewNav.tsx

```
return (
    <Navbar>
    ......
    ......
    ......
    </Navbar>
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJs - Conditional Rendering or hiding component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53432498/reactjs-conditional-rendering-or-hiding-component)

Comment: You can use react-router-dom useLocation hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will hide `<NewNav />` component when route is `/check`

```
render() {
     return (
         window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] !== "check" && <NewNav />
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to display components based on the route in the url (/check, /login, /register, etc), then you'll need react-router-dom for that. It's better this way than manually checking for the url pathname.